# Validate multiselect pick list with jQuery

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to validate multiselect pick list(if no selection is there then it should pop up an alert) through jQuery since we can't make it as require with visualforce page(actually we can but getting issues while submitting). I am unable to validate multi select pick list through this jQuery, can anyone tell me the mistake I am doing?. As validating multi pick list is different from others I am getting this issue.

Here is a piece from my page:

```
<apex:page controller="Mycontroller" docType="html-5.0" showHeader="false"  sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" >       
 <head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, '/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js')}"  />
  <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, '/js/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js')}"  />
  <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, '/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.css')}"  />   
        <script> 
   $('frm').on('submit', function(e) {
    if(!$('[name="impcat"]').valid()) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

          </script>      
      </head>
 <apex:form styleClass="form-style-9" id="frm">  
  <apex:pageBlock id="frm1" mode="maindetail">
<div id="coll1">         
  <apex:outputLabel value="Select categories?" style="font-family:Arial"/>                                        
   <apex:inputField value="{!Obj__c.Category__c}" styleClass="field-style field-split align-left" id="impcat" />                   
         </div>
</apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: why dont you use the `required` attribute of the inputField?

Comment: Thank you for your insight glls!! actually I tried with that, but the issue is, it's asking to highlight the pick list values even after selecting(chosen) the values. As it's not a best UI practice I turned to this option.

Comment: you can combine it with an onblur or change event to validate the input and take action

Comment: then I have to go for javascript right, sorry I tried that too but unable to find a way to validate through javascript.

Comment: think performing validation on email, phone, date, and number is different from multi select pick list and I am already having all those validations in my current page. And even in the specified link also using jquery to validate and my current question is also on jquery validation.

Comment: not really - your question in essence remains the same as the linked duplicate, how and what you chose to validate is up to you, regardless of JQuery, JQuery is just a javascript library that simplifies writing javscript code (simply put)